# Spring Integration returns 500 error instead of 400 error

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

I really need your advise regarding error handling in Spring Integration when using its `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` class for outbound gateway.

At the moment everything works fine for xml-config defined below except returning actual error code. For example, when I call `${http.url}/profiles?pid={pid}` with non-existing parameter `pid` instead of correct call `${http.url}/profiles?vin={vin}` with existing parameter `vin`, I always get 500-error (Internal Server Error) instead of expected 400-error (Bad Request).

Any ideas would be appreciated!

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="service.rest.profiles"
                          request-channel="service.rest.profilesChannel"
                          path="/profiles"
                          payload-expression="#requestParams.vin"
                          message-converters="service.rest.jsonMessageConverter"
                          header-mapper="service.rest.headerMapper"
                          error-channel="service.rest.httpErrorInputChannel"
                          reply-channel="service.rest.httpResponseChannel"
                          supported-methods="GET"/>

<int:channel id="service.rest.profilesChannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="service.rest.profilesChannel"
                       ref="service.rest.profileRestService" method="getProfiles"/>

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<bean id="api.rest.errorHandler"
      class="org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler"/>

..........

<int:channel id="api.json.rest.profilesChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="${http.url}/profiles?vin={vin}"
        request-channel="api.json.rest.profilesChannel"
        http-method="GET"
        message-converters="api.rest.jsonMessageConverter"
        header-mapper="api.rest.headerMapper"
        error-handler="api.rest.errorHandler"
        expected-response-type="com.example.ProfilesResponse">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="vin" expression="payload"/>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

For mentioned above 500-error I'm getting the following record in the log file:

```
19-May-2020 15:12:37.665 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/service-rest] threw exception
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'pid' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:109)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:265)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:309)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:253)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

5xx errors represent a server error; 4xx errors are returned by the server due to some problem with the request from the client.

If you are getting a 500 error when you expect a 4xx error then it means the servers is not properly handling the condition and returning the wrong status code.

Comment: Please, share in your question stack trace. Probably we handle request variable wrong way and should really throw a `BadRequest` instead of some `MessageHandlingException`...

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I added stacktrace to the main post.

Comment: So, it expects `vin`, but you send `pid`. Then it is indeed a `BadRequest` - 404, not 500. Please, raise a GH issue and will fix it in the next version!

Comment: See GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3283